# Dual Monitor support on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: multiple-monitors

I installed Windows Server 2008 R2, on my home machine. I have two 24 inches monitors connected to this machine, but windows server doesn't seem to support them. Usually in Windows 7 there is an Windows Update that install the driver that does the magic, but Windows Server don't have this driver updates.

What can I do, suppose that I can, to fix it?

Edit: it seems to be a known issue, when HyperV is enabled on the server.
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/understanding-high-end-video-performance-issues-with-hyper-v)

Answer (score 2):

Install the driver. You know. MANUALLY. Download it from the manufacturer site, install it.

Comment: You might try the Win 7 driver, if there is not a driver specifically listed for 2008 R2 on the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: Installing this driver, doesn't solve the issue. http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=josSesOqQ4beYp0n

Comment: Then use the one from the manufacturer. It is an ATI 5450.

Comment: It will NOT solve the problem. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/11/16/understanding-high-end-video-performance-issues-with-hyper-v.aspx